# Jest how to loop through similar test functions

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I know that with Jest Globals, if you have same function to be tested with different test parameters, instead of repeating this:

```
describe('test year functions', () => {
    it('should return correct year', () => {
        expect(getYear(testYear)).toBe(1990);
    });
    it('should return correct year + 1', () => {
        expect(getYear(testYear + 1)).toBe(1991);
    });
});
```

We can do this to avoid repeating `it`, which is great:

```
describe('test year functions', () => {
    test.each`
        year         | addYear  | expected
        ${testYear}  | ${0}     | ${1990}
        ${testYear}  | ${1}     | ${1991}
    `('returns correct years', ({ year, addYear, expected }) => {
        expect(getYear(testYear + addYear)).toBe(expected);
    });
});
```

Now I have different functions to be tested, but the tests are quite similar:

```
describe('test date functions', () => {
    it('getYear(date) should return correct year', () => {
        expect(getYear(1990)).toBe(1990);
    });
    it('getMonth(date) should return correct month', () => {
        expect(getMonth(testMonth + 1)).toBe(10);
    });
});
```

Can I avoid the repeat of `it` and do something like this?

```
describe('test date functions', () => {
    test.each`
        function    | parameter         | expected
        ${getYear}  | ${1990}           | ${1990}
        ${getMonth} | ${testMonth + 1}  | ${10}
    `('returns correct dates', ({ function, parameter, expected }) => {
        expect(function(parameter)).toBe(expected);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You just need to change one thing:

1. Replace `function` for other word because it is a reserved word:

```
 describe('test date functions', () => {
      test.each`
              func    | parameter         | expected
          ${getYear}  | ${1990}           | ${1990}
          ${getMonth} | ${testMonth + 1}  | ${10}
      `('returns correct dates', ({ func, parameter, expected }) => {
          expect(func(parameter)).toBe(expected);
      });
 });
```

I tried it and it worked.